# the radius of convergence of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume that $a$, and $b$ are fixed complex numbers with $a\neq{0}$. Prove that the radius of convergence of the power series $$1+az+a(a-2b){\frac{z^2}{2!}}+a{(a-3b)^2}{\frac{z^3}{3!}}+\cdots$$ is $1/e|b|.$ I tried working it out using the lim sup of the $n$-th roots, and the ratio test but cannot seem to get anywhere! Here is a sketch of my approach.

I am treating the case $b\neq 0$. Let the $n$-th coefficient be $A_n$. If I assume that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}{\frac{n}{(n!)^{1/n}}}=e,$$ an assertion that is an immediate consequence of Stirling's formula, then I can write $$A_n = \frac{a(a-nb)^{n-1}}{n!}=-{\frac{a(n^{n-1})(b^{n-1})(1-{\frac{a}{bn}})^{n-1}}{n!}}.$$ Thus, $$|A_n|^{1/n}={\frac{|a|^{1/n}n(n)^{-1/n}|b||b|^{-1/n}|1-(a/bn)||1-a/bn|^{1/n}}{(n!)^{1/n}}}.$$ Now taking limits as $n\rightarrow{\infty},$ the right hand side converges to $|b|\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}{\frac{n}{n^{1/n}}}=|b|e$, which is what we want. I feel a little foolish having to engage in the above messy calculation! Am I missing the forest for the trees and an easy answer? Wouldn't be the first time!

Comment: What is the coefficient of $z^n$, exactly?

Comment: The coefficient is $a(a-nb)^{n-1}/n!$. I am posing the question as it was asked. This question is an exercise from a complex analysis textbook. The first 2 terms do not fit the pattern! So your point is well taken.

Comment: ...And then we are left with a banal application of the root test, not so messy as you pretend.

Comment: Sorry to miss your point! Can you elaborate?

Comment: Write the coefficients as $\frac{a}{a-nb}\cdot \frac{(a-nb)^n}{n!}$. For all large enough $n$, we have $\frac{1}{2} n\lvert b\rvert < \lvert a-nb\rvert < 2n\lvert b\rvert$ (unless $b = 0$), so the $n^{\text{th}}$ root of the modulus of the first factor tends to $1$, You can therefore ignore that and concentrate on the second. The $n{\text{th}}$ root of the second factor's modulus is $$\frac{\lvert a - nb\rvert}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$$ which can be handled with a small part of Stirling's formula.

Comment: It's a perfectly good answer and about as simple as possible. The calculation of  $\lim_n|A_n|^{1/n}$ as you have presented it is perfectly clear.

Comment: Stirling's formula in some form seems unavoidable in order to find the radius of convergence whether one employs the root test, or the ratio test.

Comment: @student "Stirling's formula in some form seems unavoidable..." Without Stirling formula, in any form: $$\frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}}=\frac{a-nb}n\left(1+\frac b{nb-(a+b)}\right)^{n-2}\longrightarrow-be$$ because, for every $\alpha$ and $\beta$, if $n\alpha_n\to\alpha$ and $\beta_n/n\to\beta$, then $$\left(1+\alpha_n\right)^{\beta_n}\longrightarrow e^{\alpha\beta}$$

Comment: The above proof vindicates your first comment : the ratio test is indeed preferable to the root test in this case-and the above proof is the simplest.

Comment: @student Please read better: **if** one tries the root test **then** it works, and not messily at all. **And** the ratio test is preferable to the root test. (Unrelated: Please use @, that is, unless you want to **avoid** being read.)

Answer (score 0):

*(amended)*

The correct rendering of the series is
$$
\eqalign{
  & F(z) = 1 + az + a\left( {a - 2b} \right){{z^{\,2} } \over {2!}} + a\left( {a - 3b} \right)^{\,2} {{z^{\,3} } \over {3!}} +  \cdots  =   \cr 
  &  = 1 + a\left( {z + \left( {a - 2b} \right){{z^{\,2} } \over {2!}} + \left( {a - 3b} \right)^{\,2} {{z^{\,3} } \over {3!}} +  \cdots } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = 1 + a\left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {\left( {a - kb} \right)^{\,k - 1} {{z^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = 1 - a\left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} a^{\,k - 1} \left( {{{kb} \over a} - 1} \right)^{\,k - 1} {{z^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = 1 + az\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} a^{\,k} \left( {{{\left( {k + 1} \right)b} \over a} - 1} \right)^{\,k} {{z^{\,k} } \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)!}}} } \right) \cr} 
$$

Now, note that , for large $k$, we can write
$$
\eqalign{
  & F(z) = 1 + a\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} a^{\,k} \left( {{{\left( {k + 1} \right)b} \over a} - 1} \right)^{\,k}
 {{z^{\,k + 1} } \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  \approx 1 + a\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} a^{\,k} \left( {{{\left( {k + 1} \right)b} \over a}} \right)^{\,k}
 {{z^{\,k + 1} } \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = 1 + a\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,k} {{\left( {bz} \right)^{\,k} } \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)!}}}
  = 1 + a\,W_{\,0} (bz) \cr} 
$$
that is, that $F(z)$ is asymptotic to the [Lambert Function][1] $W_0(bz)$
whose radius of convergence is in fact $|bz|=1/e$.

Note: I am not a "theorist", and I am conscious that the above
is not a rigorous definition, but the substance is there.  I hope you or other readers can put it
in rigorous terms.

Comment: So what is the radius of convergence that you calculate? I need to show that it is $1/e|b|$. In particular it does not depend on $a$. I understand your calculations, but cannot link them to the radius of convergence.

Comment: @student: if that is the correct interpretation of the series, then the radius of convergence is infinite.

Comment: But that is incorrect. It only holds if $b=0$ in which case, as you have calculated, our function is $e^{az}$. But if $b\neq{0}$, then the radius of convergence-as worked out above using both the root and ratio tests, is $1/e|b|$.

Comment: For example, if $a=1$, and $b=1/2$, then the above answer involves dividing by $0$, and would not be valid-so your calculation must have an error. At the penultimate step, you divide by$(a-2b)$ which is where the problem seems to lie.

Comment: Sorry! Another mistake is that you have assumed that the $n$-th coefficient is $\frac{a(a-2b)^{n-1}}{n!}$. This is an error. It is in fact $\frac{a(a-nb)^{n-1}}{n!}$.

Comment: Ah! ok, you are right concerning the wrong writing of the coefficient. I will amend it, sorry.

Comment: @student: I have corrected the coefficients definition now, and the answer although not rigorous, shall help you to solve your problem (hopefully)

Comment: Indeed-but this requires to use the known facts about the power series associated with the Lambert function-though the linkage with a Lambert function may be interesting. However, the final proof by Did gives the answer in a simple and elegant way-relying on the ratio test and the standard definition of $e$ as the limit of a sequence. (Please see the above proof)!

Comment: @student: you are right: Did's answer is more simple and elegant. In any case that's good that mine complements that